# django не видит файлы static

Tags: python-3.x, django

Возникла такая проблема, django тупо не видит файлы static, какие бы я методы не использовал - ноль реакции.
На данный момент все выглядит вот так:

Так выглядит структура проекта проекта -->

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В sttings.py все вроде подключено надлежащим образом.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
```

Строка 'django.contrib.staticfiles' присутсвует в INSTALLED_APPS.

Так выглядит файл urls.py -->

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from something.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home),
    ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

В HTML файле все тоже подключено вроде -->

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Monkeys</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/file.css' %}"/>
    </head>
```

Добрые люди, подкиньте идей, где кроется ошибка?

Comment: `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: Конечно,  все как положено

Comment: А какая в отрендереном html теге link ссылка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, так что оглашаю его не актуальным, ответом было изменение STATIC_DIRS на STATICFILES_DIRS и после этого снова прогнать команду `collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй указать абсолютный путь до статики. Например:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/practice/static/',
)
```

Статик рут тебе понадобится уже при развёртывании проекта.